# Check in Java program what GPU is installed

Tags: java, gpu

I'm writing a Java program that uses external C++ .exe applications:

- CUDA for nVidia GPU
- OpenCL for AMD GPU

to do some high-performance calculations for my Java app that is basically used for online communication and DB storage.
What I'm struggling with is:

**how to check in my Java app what GPU is installed on current computer (so that the app would know which external .exe to run)?**

No, I'm not trying to do Java GPU programming. Java used on Windows (mostly 7, 8 and 8.1). Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could use one of the OpenCL bindings for Java to perform a device query. Such a query would allow you to detect whether there are NVIDIA- or AMD GPUs available. (Disclaimer: I'm the developer of http://www.jocl.org/ ).

Comment: That should do the trick. Will it be no-gpu-installed safe?

Answer (score 0):

Think about using JNA or JNI and make your decision there what implementation you will use, i think its much cleaner than calling an external .exe file, also you are safe if you want to support other platforms too at a further time.

Update: If you wanna have access to native things that you normally can't get with plain java, look at this powerful library: https://support.hyperic.com/display/SIGAR/Home

Comment: The problem is that I've already got both external C++ apps and it's not really my call to do it another way. Appllication isn't supossed to be cross-platform.